# What is a (proposed) “Record” class in C# 6?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

**I believe this never made it into C# 6k, but may be considered for a later release.**

I have just read a [very confusing blog](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/Pattern-Matching) talking about pattern matching and record classes in C# 6 along with the operator “is”.

Please can someone give me a overview of what all this is about in such a way as I can understand what effect it will have on C# code I write once C# 6 ships.

(Please note this has nothing to do with databases!   But Google thinks it does...)

---

I read [Pattern Matching in C# 6 and VB 12](http://infoq.com/news/2014/08/Pattern-Matching) first before finding [Easier Immutable Objects in C# 6 and VB 12](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/Record-Class) - reading them in the other order makes a lot more sence.

If Record classes solve the:

> Currently most ORMs and serializers don’t have support for immutable
>   types. Instead, they assume there will be a parameterless constructor
>   and mutable properties.

Problem by standardising how immutable types are created, then I can see them being great regardless of pattern matching.

Comment: Please link to the blog post, otherwise it's hard to get any context.

Comment: [Various](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/Record-Class) [links](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/560339) [here](http://enumeratethis.com/2014/08/11/record-types-pattern-matching-coming-in-c-6/), but not sure which was the source. Personally I quite like the look of all that, Instapaper'd :-)

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/Pattern-Matching is the blog post however I think it maybe missing the point

Comment: This maybe: http://enumeratethis.com/2014/08/11/record-types-pattern-matching-coming-in-c-6/ ?

Comment: It wasn't that confusing. What will be confusing is sorting out the messy recursive Type patterns that junior devs will try to write.

Comment: Think of it as objects that you can switch case over instead of primitives. might sound strange but it is great when building message based systems or compilers etc.

Comment: kidna funny as there was nothing stopping you doing this by hand before - except that all the microsoft technologies depend on having writable properties for serialisation, orm layers etc. I hope this implies that they intend to change these so we can have objects with predictable state in the future. IE cool stuff, but how can you really use them given current state of play (no pun intended)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/Record-Class):

> This is essentially an immutable class defined solely by its
>   constructor. Here is an example from the specification:
>
> ```
> public record class Cartesian(double x: X, double y: Y);
> ```
>
> In addition to the constructor, the compiler will automatically
>   create:
>
> - A read-only property for each parameter
> - An Equals function
> - A GetHashCode override
> - A ToString Override
> - An “is” Operator, known as “Matches” in VB

I just read this [PROPOSAL: Records, and Plain Old CLR Objects](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/543522)

> Imagine something called a "Record", a type with an ordered list of
>   named data members. Not saying there should be a new kind of type
>   called a "record type" alongside classes and structs... indeed it
>   might be best not to have a new kind of type, since we might want
>   record-like classes and structs.

**PROPOSAL 1:** a record can be defined using primary-constructor syntax, and it is syntactic sugar for an expanded form as follows...

```
class Point(int X, int Y);

==>

class Point(int X, int Y)
{
   public int X { get; } = X;
   public int Y { get; } = Y;
}
```

The rule is: "When you write a record, it automatically generates properties for the PRIMARY PROPERTIES, unless you have provided those properties yourself". The term "Primary Properties" refers to the parameters in the primary-constructor syntax. Thus, if you didn't want it to auto-generate a property, you'd have to provide your own version of that property, as in the example below. (There's no way to say that you don't want the property with this syntax: if you don't want the property, then don't use the feature at all).

```
class Point(int X, int Y) { public int X => 15; }

==>

class Point(int X, int Y)
{
   public int X => 15;
   public int Y {get; set;} = Y;
}
```

Comment: Now just watch as the C# language team avoids the use/implementation of an actual "record" keyword. Everything I see on the GitHub page shows them using already-implemented syntaxes, where it basically looks like a class declaration. Maybe if we're lucky, someone on the team will actually have an existential realization and try to add a proper 'record' keyword for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this discussion](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/560339), it's a way for the compiler generate immutable types (`class` or `struct`) ready for pattern matching and with record semantics.

The compiler will generate an `is` operator for pattern matching and `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString` methods with record semantics.

Comment: Just some more syntactic sugar with no real world use case :p

Comment: @Jay, do you really think the team has that much time to throw around?

Comment: I dunno, with primary constructors and all one can only wonder!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this only adds some syntactic sugar and in some very nitche cases and you shouldn't change old code you should adopt it if the scenario arrives and helps your paradigm,  otherwise its just there.

This is similar to exception filters and comes from the need to be able to have F# patterns implemented in C#.

Lets consider the 'is' overload,  this construct allows for special filtering by the compiler but is in no way more performant then simply filtering the clause yourself.

E.g

'if (x is Something) return (x as Something).Value > 0'

Becomes something like

'x is (Something, 1)'

The problem anyone failed to realise is that when x is Something via the virtues of something else either via inheritance or interface and those properties are virtual this could be tricky to debug especially when each type may have a im implicit or explicit cast overload for Something.

Additionally the 'Record' concept is nothing different than an anonymous type which has a type with the underlying.

E.g. a Record of Something simply provides a wrapper around Record with your properties as immutable and a hashcode. (only again as syntactic sugar this time to support Primary constructors which have another set of gotchas, e.g. when the inheriting type defines a property which is generated by the derivative type, hiding occurs and you end up having to type everything out anyway)

Hopefully that answers that.